# Design Patterns for WP8 Apps

Tags: windows-phone-8

I have a query regarding the Windows Phone 8 applications.
I want to design one WP8 App to be submitted to the Windows Phone App store, Is it compulsory to use a design pattern, like MVVM or MVC, for the App?

Comment: No, how should the app store be able to verify that you are using MVVM or even care? They only care about certain behavior of your app and you can find guides on what is required when you submit an app which I highly recommend that you study.